# Show that $ E\Big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X_n})^2\Big] = (n-1)\sigma^2 $

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

> $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are i.i.d random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. $\bar{X_n} = S_n/n$ where $S_n = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n$. Show that

$$ E\Big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - \bar{X_n})^2\Big] = (n-1)\sigma^2 $$

Attempt:

$$ E\Big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - X_n)^2\Big] = E\Big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}~X_i^2 - 2X_i\bar{X_n} + \bar{X_n}^2\Big] \tag{1} $$

$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{n}E\Big(X_i^2 - 2X_i\bar{X_n} + \bar{X_n}^2) \tag{2} $$

$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\Big(E(X_i^2) - 2E(X_i\bar{X_n}) + E(\bar{X_n}^2)\Big) \tag{3} $$

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: The indices $i$ and parenthesis suddenly disappeared while simplifying. Take the sum first then take expectation. Plus you got (a-b)^2 wrong.

Comment: ok i added the indices even though they're all iid.. and i fixed the sign mistake.

Comment: @StubbornAtom would you mind showing me how to do the sum

Comment: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459555/bessels-correction/3459637#3459637)

Comment: @StubbornAtom I had defined my $X$ above my attempt.

Comment: @VictorS. Okay I missed that.

Comment: Duplicate of [Mean of $ \sum (X_i - \bar{X})^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701626/mean-of-sum-x-i-barx2).

Answer (score 1):

Observe that
$$
(X_i-\mu)^2=(X_i-\bar{X})^2+(\bar{X}-\mu)^2+2(X_i-\bar{X})(\bar{X}-\mu)
$$
and moreover
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})(\bar{X}-\mu)=(\bar{X}-\mu) \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})=0
$$whence
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2+\sum_{i=1}^n(\bar{X}-\mu)^2.
$$
In particular
$$
\begin{align}
n\sigma^2=n\text{Var}(X_1)=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\mu)^2\right]
&=
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2\right]+
E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(\bar{X}-\mu)^2\right]\\
&=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2\right]+n\text{Var}(\bar{X})\\
&=E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar{X})^2\right]+\sigma^2
\end{align}
$$
from which the desired result follows.

Answer (score 1):

$$E\Big[\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i - X_n)^2\Big]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\Big(E(X_i^2) - 2E(X_i\bar{X_n}) + E(\bar{X_n}^2)\Big)$$

We have

$$E(X_i^2)=\sigma^2+\mu^2$$

$$E(X_i\bar{X_n})=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{E(X_i X_k)}=E(X_i^2)+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1, k \ne i}^{n}{E(X_i)E( X_k)}$$
because $X_i$'s are independent.
Thus,
$$E(X_i\bar{X_n})=\sigma^2+\mu^2+\frac{n-1}{n}\mu^2$$

Also,

$$E(\bar{X_n}^2)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}{E(X_iX_j)}=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{E(X_i^2)}+{\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{\sum_{j=1, i\ne j}^{n}{E(X_i)E(X_j)}}}$$

Therefore,
$$E(\bar{X_n}^2)=\frac{n}{n^2}(\sigma^2+\mu^2)+\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}\mu^2$$

Finally add them up, and you have the results wanted.